# How to pause game running in background during asynchronous event?

Tags: asynchronous, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I am creating a game in GMS2. I am using "show_message_async()" in my code. I know that when it is run, a message pops up on the screen and the game still runs in the background. However, I want the game to freeze in the background while the message pops up. Is it possible to do this? And if so how.

Answer (score 1):

You should try looking up `instance_deactivate_all(notme)` and `instance_activatie_all(notme)`

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/deactivating%20instances/index.html

This will disable all objects in a room except the object that's calling it (which should be the menu object that shows the message)

The only tricky part of it, it that it also disables drawing the objects. resulting in an empty screen. For this,  you could either use a black screen, or draw a screenshot of the scene before they're disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Steven's answer. To add on his answer about taking the screenshot of the game, you probably need to make a new surface, then use surface_copy from application_surface before deactivating the object.